# Can't bind command to Spacebar in Sublime Text

Tags: windows, macros, sublimetext3

I'm using this two bindings for auto complete:

```
{
"keys": ["tab"],
"command": "move",
"args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true},
"context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
{
"keys": ["shift+tab"],
"command": "move",
"args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false},
"context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
```

I would like to add `"commit_completion"` command to `space` key:

```
"keys": ["space"],
"command": "commit_completion",
"context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
```

But it's not binding, when I press `space` it acts as normal space(it makes space xD). I'm able to bind it to any other key but not space. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a key code for the space bar that you can bind like that; if you want to bind something to space, you need to use a literal space character:

```json
{
  "keys": [" "],
  "command": "commit_completion",
  "context": [
    { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
  ]
},
```

This is visible in the Sublime console by using `sublime.log_input(True)` to turn on input logging and then pressing the key; the only thing that gets logged is a character event, and not a key event.

It's also important to note that you never want to bind anything to a character like this unless you're using a `context` to constrain when the binding applies, or you lose the ability to type that character.